# How to rename values in a dataframe based on breakpoint values?

Tags: r

I'm working with an imported data set that has a column with value ranging from 1 to 1000+ called "transacation_level". The goal is to overwrite the values with x >= 1000 is "high", x < 100 is "low", and anything inbetween is "medium". I'm trying the following code:

```
transaction_level[transaction_level >= 1000] <- "high"
transaction_level[transaction_level >=100 & < 1000] <- "medium"
transaction_level[transaction_level < 100] <- "low"
```

However, not all of the values are being overwritten correctly. For example, 5.99 does not get overwritten as "low". At the same time, row already overwritten as "high" are getting rewritten in some cases as "medium". Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: `transaction_level >=100 & < 1000` doesn't work in R you would need `transaction_level >=100 & transaction_level < 1000`

Comment: Also in your first step you coerce what is I guess an integer to character so your next two steps are meaningless

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at `cut`?

```
min_value <- min(transaction_level)
max_value <- max(transaction_level)
transaction_level <- cut(transaction_level,
  breaks = c(min_value, 100, 1000, max_value),
  labels = c("low", "medium", "high")
)
```

and of course, if you want a character instead of a factor at the end, just put `as.character` around it.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't remember if it needed a min and max as well, or just the interior ones.  glad it worked!  (also, since I have no idea what your min and max values are, you were likely to get errors in that respect anyways).

Comment: Min was just 0 thankfully. I used an arbitrary large value for the max cutoff point. It was (0,100,1000,100000).